# FileObserver functionality on Android 11+

Tags: android

I am trying to monitor external Download folder changes on Android 11+, but no events are triggered. I used `FileObserver( ... ).startWatching()` method with File as input parameter.

I already grant the runtime permission `ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`

Is it a way to monitor file changes, other one than do pooling, which is not good in therms of power management?

Documentation does not say it does not work on Android 11+